# Creating Django application inside of the project directory hierarchy?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, hierarchy

In [django rest framework quick start](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/#:%7E:text=It%20may%20look%20unusual%20that%20the%20application%20has%20been%20created%20within%20the%20project%20directory) it creates the application inside of parent project directory instead of the top-level hierarchy for the sake of preventing conflicts with other packages. I'm asking is there any other benefit to this approach or on the other hand it will add overhead to the performance because of extra nesting?